# Making variable empty set

Tags: prolog

I am implementing some of the built in prolog functions as practice. However, I am running into trouble in intersection and difference because in my base recursive case I need to set my return value to an empty set. I have no idea how to do this and looking around I haven't found an answer.

When I run the code I get the following:

```
1 ?- intersectionx([1,2,3],[3,4,5],Z).
Z = [3|_G3196] .

2 ?- differencex([1,2,3],[3,4,5],Z).
Z = [1, 2|_G3181]
```

Here is the actual line by line with relevant predicates on lines 16 and 22.

```
/* memberx */
/* test is X a member of set Y, X subset Y */
memberx(X1,[X1|_]).
memberx(X2,[_|T2]) :- memberx(X2, T2).

/* unionx */
/* union sets X and Y and return the resulting set as Z. */
unionx([], Y3, Y3).             /* base case */
unionx([XH4|XT4], Y4, Z4) :- memberx(XH4, Y4), unionx(XT4, Y4, Z4).
unionx([XH5|XT5], Y5, [XH5|Z5]) :- not(memberx(XH5, Y5)), unionx(XT5, Y5, Z5).

/* intersectionx ???*/
/* Find the intersection of sets X and Y and return the result as set */
/* Z. X intersection Y = Z */
intersectionx([], Y6, Z6). /*In the base case here how do I set Z6 to []?*/
intersectionx([XH7|XT7], Y7, Z7) :- not(memberx(XH7, Y7)), intersectionx(XT7, Y7, Z7).
intersectionx([XH8|XT8], Y8, [XH8|Z8]) :- memberx(XH8, Y8), intersectionx(XT8, Y8, Z8).

/* differencex */
/* Find the difference of set X and Y and return the result as set Z. */
differencex([], Y9, Z9).
differencex([XH10|XT10], Y10, [XH10|Z10]) :- not(memberx(XH10, Y10)), differencex(XT10, Y10, Z10).
differencex([XH10|XT10], Y10, Z10) :- memberx(XH10, Y10), differencex(XT10, Y10, Z10).
```

I know this is probably a relatively simple thing, but it has been baffling me for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

```
intersectionx([], _, []).
```

I find your numbering of variables a little strange. Is there a reason you did that? You can use the same variable names in different predicates without trouble.

Comment: actually it should be `intersectionx([], _, []).`

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something simple I just didn't know what.

I number the variables that way because I am copying an old homework assignment where I had to do all this in clausal form and the professor demanded we number that way. I initially copy pasted it from the old doc so they are an artifact of that. I am about to go about stripping them out.

Comment: Glad to help. I sometimes wonder what degree of Prolog's decline in popularity is owing to bizarre behavior on the part of professors. Thanks for giving it another shot. :)